# javascript or jquery simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem. I don't know JavaScript or jQuery; only HTML, CSS, PHP, and design.  I need a simple jQuery function, but I don't know how to do it.

I need to make a call to the following webservice:

- http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?act=count&url=http://viberieto.ru/

This function returns a number near ')'.  I need to display this number in `<div id="count">`.

How do I do that? Can you help me?

Comment: it's not my site. I just want to display number from it url in my site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of restriction due to crossdomain policy you probably need get the data through jsonp.
Luckily this is easily done with jQuery.

```
$.getScript("http://vkontakte.ru/share.php?act=count&url=http://viberieto.ru/");
```

This will create a new script tag containing the code returned by the webservice. To handle the response you'll need to create a object structure like the one from the url:

```
var VK = {
  Share: {
    count: function(arg1, arg2) {
      // Insert the value into the div
      $('#count').html(arg2);
    }
  }
};
VK
```

Edit: Fixed typo